# UWP App working on desktop, but crash on windows phone

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

Consider the following code which draws a line on the UWP MapControl:

```
if (mPoints.Count >= 2)
{
  var shape = new MapPolyline
  {
     StrokeThickness = 3,
     StrokeColor = Colors.Green,
     StrokeDashed = true,
     ZIndex = 1,
     Path = new Geopath(mPoints.Take(2))
  };
  mapControl.MapElements.Add(shape);
```

It works on windows 10 desktop, but crashes on mPoints.Take(2) (mPoints has 2 elements) on Windows Phone

Changing it to the following fixes the problem:

```
List<BasicGeoposition> l = new List<BasicGeoposition>() { mPoints[0], mPoints[1] };

                    var shape = new MapPolyline
                    {
                        StrokeThickness = 3,
                        StrokeColor = Colors.Green,
                        StrokeDashed = true,
                        ZIndex = 1,
                        Path = new Geopath(l)
                    };
                    mapControl.MapElements.Add(shape);
```

But I'd really like to know why the Linq version is not working on windows phone? Is this a bug in the uwp platform, am I using Take wrong or is this not implemented yet?

BTW, it was tested on a Lumia 930 and a Lumia 650, it crashed on both

Comment: what is the exception?

Comment: What is the exact type and source of `mPoints`? I have tried your code with a `List<BasicGeoposition>` and `Take` does not throw.